# .NET — Что происходит в памяти при присвоении значения структуры к переменной типа object?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Что происходит в памяти процесса в .NET при присвоении экземпляра значимого типа к переменной типа object. Что хранится в этой переменной?

```
int a = 5;
object obj = a;
```

Comment: Упаковка-распаковка. Но вообще это "преданья старины глубокой", сейчас про это даже на собеседованиях никто не спрашивает. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing